# Doctrine 2 throws QueryException on production server but not on developement server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, doctrine-orm

The code below has been working fine on my production server for sometime now. But now suddenly throws QueryException.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT c, m, u, t FROM Invetico\ContentBundle\Entity\Serminar c LEFT JOIN c.menu m LEFT JOIN c.user u LEFT JOIN c.term t WHERE t.slug = :slug AND c.status = :status ORDER BY c.datePublished DESC' in /home/zibaconsult/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41
```

The strange thing is on my developement machine nothing happens. No Fatal errors.

Below is the code

```
    private function getContentQuery($contentType = '')
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $class = ($contentType !='')?$contentType:'Invetico\ContentBundle\Entity\Content';
    $qb->select('c','m','u','t')
       ->from($class, 'c')
       ->leftJoin('c.menu','m')
       ->leftJoin('c.user', 'u')
       ->leftJoin('c.term', 't');
    return $qb;
}

public function findContentTypeByTerm($contentType, $term, $limit)
{
    $qb = $this->getContentQuery($contentType)
        ->where('t.slug = :slug')
        ->andWhere('c.status = :status')
        ->orderBy('c.datePublished', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('slug',$term)
        ->setParameter('status',1)
        ->setFirstResult(0)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);    
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();        
}

    public function buildTermWidget(WidgetInterface $widget)
{
    $view = $this->createView($widget);
    $view->collection = $this->contentRepository->findContentTypeByTerm($widget->getContentType(), $widget->getTerm(), $widget->getRecordLimit());
    return $view;   
}
```

I do not know if the different versions of mysql server on both the production and development is causing this problem.

Development Machine: Linux Ubuntu,Xampp - Mysql 5.6.14 - Source distribution

Production Machine: Linux CentOS - Mysql 5.5.36-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I do not have access to the production server.

[Edit]The error message below

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT c, m, u, t FROM Invetico\ContentBundle\Entity\Serminar c LEFT JOIN c.menu m LEFT JOIN c.user u LEFT JOIN c.term t WHERE t.slug = :slug AND c.status = :status ORDER BY c.datePublished DESC' in /home/zibaconsult/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41 
Stack trace:
#0 /home/zibaconsult/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(483): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT c, m, u,...') 
#1 /home/zibaconsult/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1042): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('Class Invetico\...') 
#2 /home/zibaconsult/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1688): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->JoinAssociationPathExpression() 
#3 /home/zibaconsult/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1628): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->JoinAssociationDeclaration() 
#4 /home/zibaconsult/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1558): Doctr in /home/zibaconsult/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 63
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to indicate which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: The site this code is deployed on was working ok until today. I no have no idea if there has been some changes on the server with respect to mysql database. It works ok on my development machine. the calling cade `$this->contentRepository->findContentTypeByTerm($widget->getContentType(), $widget->getTerm(), $widget->getRecordLimit());` should work perfectly